# How to wall-mount this whiteboard

Tags: walls, installation, brick, mount

[image: image of obstruction on wall]

Trying to mount a 1/2" thick white board (2' tall, 8' wide) on this brick wall. The challenge is doing so with these electrical tubes in the way (they come about 1.5" off the wall). Any suggestions?

I'm sure there's some bracket or strategy that can be used, just can't seem to figure it out.

Bonus points: a removable mount of some kind!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just mount a couple 2x4's horizontally on the wall with whatever anchor you prefer, and mount the white board to the 2x4's.  A regular 2x4 is 1-1/2" thick.  The 2x4's will get you just over the conduit as long as you can avoid the set screws on the coupling.  If you need to go a little thicker, you could screw a strip of plywood on top of the 2x4's to add another 1/2" or 3/4".

Comment: Why the heck in US the regular 2x4 is called 2x4 when almost every one knows very well its thickness is only 1.5 inches? Whats wrong  with these guys in US?

Comment: You want to be outraged?  Take off your pants and measure the waist band and compare that to the number on the label.  Prepare to be really disillusioned.

Comment: At least it's not like tuna fish cans or ice cream cartons where every few years they get smaller but the price stays the same.

Comment: In the UK we have 2x4 which is 2x4 in the rough sawn state and when planed ( PAR ) it will be somewhere around 45x95mm. Note we still use a mixture of imperial as well as metric sizes after nearly 50 years!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! I just noticed a few screws and irregularities on the electrical tubing come out to about 2", but I will just add a layer of wood to accommodate it. Cheers!

Comment: You may be able to loosen the screws and rotate the fittings.